# Terminating process running in background in a Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline that uses a script step to do two things inside a loop:

1. opening an SSH tunnel by running a bash script in the background (adding  `&` at the end)
2. do some other stuff while having the SSH tunnel open

```
pipeline {
    stage('some stage') {
      steps {
        script {
          def hosts = ['host-0.service.consul', 'host-1.service.consul', 'host-2.service.consul']
          for (host in hosts){
            // kill previously opened tunnel here if it has been opened
            ???
            // run script in background
            sh "./scripts/myscript.sh &"
            // do some other stuff
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that upon each iteration I have to close the SSH tunnel by killing the process spawned with `sh "./scripts/myscript.sh &"`. However I don't know the PID of that process.

How can I do this inside a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy and/or Bash?

Not sure if this question is more related to bash or to Jenkins/Groovy

Comment: You might be able to parse the tunnel PIDs from the output of `lsof` once you `grep` for some combination of 'ssh' or 'sshd' and your hostname.

Comment: Can you `kill job 1`